# Как в Delphi в секции реализации модуля в реализации процедуры класса использовать объект, который вызвал данную процедуру?

Tags: delphi

Есть процедура:

```
Procedure TMatrix.Addition(matr:Tmatrix;var Res:TMatrix)
```

Она суммирует две матрицы. `matr` это вторая матрица, `res` - результат , а как получить объект, который вызовет данную процедуру (первую матрицу)?

Comment: Перед. его. с помощ. доп. параметра.

Comment: Плюсующие невнимательно прочитали вопрос )

> обьект который вызвет данную процедуру(_первую матрицу_)

Answer (score 1):

Если вы имеете в виду объект класса `TMatrix`, для которого был вызван метод `Addition` (например, `myMatrix.Addition(...)`), то вы можете обратиться к нему через `self`.

Если вы имеете в виду экземпляр произвольного класса, в котором вызывался код `myMatrix.Addition(...)`, то это невозможно и, как уже сказал [@Котик_хочет_кушать](/users/4149/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C), нужно передавать его параметром.